# Iterate through dynamic connectors to change colour based on text

Tags: vba, visio

I need to iterate through all dynamic connectors on a visio document and change the colour of the connector line based on the dynamic connector text label - The code is based off a previous question to change line width of dynamic connectors.

I cant find a box defining the text label

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim shp As Shape, mst As Master
' iterate all shapes per page
For Each shp In ActivePage.Shapes
    ' declare parent master for current shape
    Set mst = shp.Master
    ' Process only shapes that have parent master-shape
    If Not (mst Is Nothing) Then
        ' change only shapes, which master-shape is dynamic connector
        If mst.Name = "Dynamic connector" Then
            ' Now i dont know how to proceed - forgive me i am new to coding - i know the syntax is wrong, im just trying to give somthing to go off
            If shp.Text = "A" Then shp.Cells("LineColour").Formula = RGB(255,255,0))
        Else If shp.Text = "G" Then shp.Cells("LineColour").Formula = RGB(0,255,0))
        Else If shp.Text = "R" Then shp.Cells("LineColour").Formula = RGB(255,0,0))
    End If
    End
```

But shape text does not appear to be a property - even though the connector defiantly  has text, and properties of this text such as font do appear.

Any help would be great - cheers

Comment: I see If without End If, an unwrapped For Each loop... This code won't execute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
ActivePage.Shapes(shp.Name).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello World!"

'or

shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Hello World!"


' This macro works in Excel
Sub Macro1()
Dim shp As Shape

Me.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeLeftArrow, 200, 200, 10, 10

For Each shp In Me.Shapes
    shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "A"
    Debug.Print shp.name, shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When using that i get the error:

Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method - Error 438

I guess that means the text cant be used?

Comment: Hm, I've added maco code from Excel, it works normally, maybe in Visio .Text property is really unavailalble.

Comment: Maybe you'll find more at MSDN: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.text) or [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.shape.alternativetext)